# Finding smaller matrix in bigger matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms

Given a bigger matrix of size R*C .Where each element of matrix is between [-20,20].

Now i need to find a smaller matrix of dimension H*W  (H <= R, W <= C) in such a way that sum of squared difference between each cell of smaller matrix and it's corresponding cell in the subgrid in bigger matrix is minimum.

Example : Let bigger matrix be of size 3*3

```
19 19 -12
5 8 -14
-12 -11 9
```

And smaller one of 2*2

```
-18 -12
-10 -7
```

Here answer is 937 which is computed as follows: (8 - (-18))^2 + (-14 - (-12))^ 2 + (-11 - (-10))^2 + (9 - (-7))^2 = 937

Now provided two matrices whose size can go upto 500*500 I need to find this sum and also the left topmost point of this subgrid which in this case is (2,2).
Please help

Comment: Do you have reason to think there is something more efficient that just calculating them all?  With the large matrix $500 \times 500$, that is only $249001$ possible upper corners, so only a few million operations.  That will take no time on a computer.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yeah..But i need an efficient algorithm for it.Please help

Comment: I don't see what structure your matrices have that can be exploited to eliminate possibilities. If you find a close match, so one of the sums is less than $100$, say, you can stop calculating when another location exceeds that.  It won't save you much.  How efficient do you think you can get?

Comment: @RossMillikan Perhaps O(N^3)?

Comment: My suggestion is $O(n^2)$-you have $n^2$ possible upper corners and a fixed number of operations for each upper corner.

Comment: @RossMillikan PLease explain .How?

Comment: @RossMillikan Currently am having O(N^4) solution for this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15520/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-user157452).

Comment: @RossMillikan I dont know how to chat over it am not getting chat box to type

Comment: If you click on the "continue this discussion in chat" it should take you to a new window.  Then log in and we will be connected.